# Problem connecting to pgsqldb flexi server with FQDN but able to connect with IP

Tags: postgresql

I have deployed pgsqldb flexi server using Terraform but having trouble connecting to it using servername . I have vpn configured poin to site . I can connect to the same db using the private ip of private DNS zone but not with the private DNS name. I couldn't even connect from virtual machine which is in the same vnet fyi same issue can connect using ip but not fqdn
I have private DNS resolver also
Please help to fix this

Private DNS resolver deployed